# How to calculate means and confidence intervals for different sample sizes automatically?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a sample of a population (n=670), where I want to investigate how the sample size affects the results. I have calculated the "true mean" of the population, and want to compare this to the mean when n=20, n=30, n=40, etc. Is there a way where R could randomly sample x number of individuals from my dataset, and calculate mean and confidence interval, for each sample size?

Would also like to plot this somehow, where the x-axis show the "accumulated" mean. The hypothesis is that the larger the sample size, the closer to the "true mean", where I want to investigate how large the sample size must be in order to get close to the true mean.

I have figured out how to sample random rows with `sample_n(data, size)`, and how to do the calculations (using `lm()` and `confint()`). But is it possible to avoid doing everything manually? Not only is the dataset of 670 individuals, but I have to do the same for two more populations (in total app 1500 individuals).

Comment: It is possible, but you need to provide us with an example of your data and what you have put together so far in order for the community to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a `for` loop with the sample sizes I am interested in, as follows:

```
sizes <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)

results <- c()

for (size in sizes) {
  subset <- sample_n(data, size)
  
  lm_fit <- lm(subset$response ~ subset$predictor)
  conf <- confint(lm_fit, level = 0.95)
  
  results <- rbind(results, c(size, lm_fit$coefficients[1], conf[1,1], conf[1,2]))
}
```

You may plot the results as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = results, aes(x = size, y = mean)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper))
```

where `geom_errorbar` helps to show the confidence interval.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! This sent me in the right direction. New to RStudio, so it is not always easy to know where to look for solutions. I ended up with the code below.

```
calculate_mean_ci_M <- function(data, subset_sizes){
mean <- mean(RandomM$Value[1:subset_sizes])
sem <- sd(RandomM$Value[1:subset_sizes]) /sqrt(subset_sizes)
ci <- sem * qt(c(0.025, 0.975), df = subset_sizes-1)
return(data.frame(subset_sizes = subset_sizes, mean = mean, ci_lower = mean - ci[1], 
                ci_upper = mean + ci[1]))
}


subset_sizes <- c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 
              150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 
              270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 370,
              380, 390, 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 500,
              510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600, 610, 620, 630,
              640, 650, 660, 670, 672)
mean_ci_data_M <- map(subset_sizes, calculate_mean_ci_M, data = data) %>%
  bind_rows()`
```